# Air flow and ventilation in an apartment with all windows on one side

Tags: windows, mold, ventilation

I am considering renting a 2 bedroom apartment with all the windows on one side(south). But I am concerned about the overall air circulation in the apartment and eventually moisture and mold problems.

[image: Floor Plann]

Is ventilation greatly compromised by this layout? Is it possible to retrofit a ventilation system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily circulate air in this scenario with forced circulation / pressurization, AKA a box fan. A fan in the bathroom and partially open windows in the other rooms will achieve suitable circulation.

I used to make use of a whole house window fan (~$200) in an apartment I lived in years ago that could push 3,560 CFM, or put another way enough to dump all the air in the entire apartment in less than five minutes. I'd leave the AC off during the day and vent the apartment in the evening rather than (or before) turning the AC on at night.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Cannot upvote, not enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The air will probably get a bit stale without some sort of fan to circulate the air. It could be a ceiling fan or a box fan in the window, either will provide some nice circulation. Mold and moisture shouldn't be a problem except in the bath, but that should have its own ventilation fan.

As far as retrofitting a ventilation system (central air?), of course it can be done. Whether one would want to depends on the cost and amount of effort needed, as compared to simply running a box fan.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Cannot upvote, not enough reputation.